# Displaying table in MessageBox

Tags: c#

Is it possible to show some type of table in a `MessageBox` in C#?

I want it to look something like this (only the text parts forget the buttons and colours):

[image]

Because right now it is like this:

[image]

How can I align the numbers to make it look nice like the top picture?

Comment: The quickest way is to just add tabs \t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to design your own form for that, the built in MessageBox will only display a message (a string), with no formatting.

Use ShowDialog() to show your form as a modal dialog box like the MessageBox does.

Comment: also you can disable FormBorderStyle Of the form to be much like your picture

Comment: Was just going to ask that.

Comment: Yes, that would be an easy way to achieve that layout.